# Recursion, Polymorphism and Inheritance confusion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two classes in Python 3.8: A and B, where B inherits from A, both classes have a method with the same name, therefore the method of class B overrides that of class A, the method in B has a parameter plus.

The function in B calls **super** ().method (condition) and the function in A calls self.method (condition) recursively, the result I expect is that when I do **super**().method (condition) in B and then **self**.method (condition) in A the method of class A is executed again, however the result obtained is that it tries to execute the method in B, throwing an error because a parameter is missing.
This is the code:

```
class A():
    def method(self, condition):
        if condition:
            print('from A')
        else:
            self.method(True)

class B(A):
    def method(self, condition, other):
        if condition:
            print('from B')
        else:
            super().method(False)

b = B()
b.method(False, 0)
```

And this is the error:

> TypeError: method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Comment: Python is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.  `object.method()` calls the version of method appropriate for `object`.  It doesn't matter where you're calling it from.  If you're calling it with a object of type `B, then it will call B's implementation of method.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above.  The simplest solution is to create a private method, so there is no confusion.

```
class A():
    def __method(self, condition):
        if condition:
            print('from A')
        else:
            self.__method(True)
    
    def method(self, condition):
        self.__method(condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   # The parameters should be same in both the methods.
    class A():
        def method(self, condition,other):
            if condition:
                print('from A')
            else:
                self.method(True)

    class B(A):
        def method(self, condition, other):
            if condition:
                print('from B')
            else:
                super().method(False)

    b = B()
    b.method(False, 0)


                  OR 
    class A():
        def method(self, condition):
            if condition:
                print('from A')
            else:
                self.method(True)

    class B(A):
        def method(self, condition):
            if condition:
                print('from B')
            else:
                super().method(False)

    b = B()
    b.method(False, 0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).